# Best way to store and represent many 1D numpy float arrays to one 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm converting .bed files into 1D numpy float arrays. Later on, I will need this 1D numpy float array. For circa 700 .bed files saving them in 1D numpy array is very costly.

My solution is to convert them into string array and consecutively concatenating them so that I can retrieve them later in the order they are concatenated. Like getting the last array as shown below.

```
import numpy as np

array_size=10000
number_of_files=700

sample1 = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(1,array_size))
s1 = np.array(["%.2f" % x for x in sample1.reshape(sample1.size)])
np.save('test',s1)

for i in range(number_of_files):
 sample = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(1,array_size))
 s = np.array(["%.2f" % x for x in sample.reshape(sample.size)]) 
 s_temp=np.load('test.npy',mmap_mode='r')   
 s_new=['%s_%s' %(x,y) for x,y in zip(s_temp,s)]
 np.save('test',s_new) 

result=np.load('test.npy')
last=[x.split('_')[100] for x in result]
```

However, my test code shows that this string array is much more costly.
Storing 1D numpy float of 250M size costs for 1.9 GB.
700 files would make 1330 GM!!!.

Storing 1D numpy string array of 10 K size costs for 143 MB.
(250M/10K)*143MB would make 3575 GB!!!

Do you have any better solution for this representation and later retrieval problem?

Comment: Explain why you think strings would be better?  By the way, with `size=(1,10000)`, that's not 1d.  It may be a 'row vector', but in `numpy` that's still 2d.  Anyways, I don't think you can do better than the normal `npy` numeric storage (adjusting `dtype` if needed).  That saves/reads the array's `data buffer` without any conversion.

Comment: You can try with [`np.savez_compressed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html), although I wouldn't expect a massive reduction (in the general case float arrays do not compress so much).

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry for the late response. I thought that saving in string format such that each value concatenated with '_' character will let us get the corresponding file's value through split('_')[order_of_file_among_all_files] later on.

Comment: @jdehesa I guess I must make a small test of it and see its size on disk.

Comment: you could try a. compress and/or b. store as np.float16 , a half-precision float, if the loss of resolution is not an issue.